# allow localhost; deny all; for all despite "index.php" and "/"

Tags: nginx, config

I'm trying to restrict direct access to .php files on web server.

Used `allow localhost;deny all;`. However, this restricts access also to `index.php`.

How to overcome this issue? Is there something like `IF conditions`?

My config:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "^(/)index\.php$") {
    return 301 $1;
}

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 

    rewrite ^/(\w+)$       /?system=$1       break;
    rewrite ^/(\w+)/(\w+)(/.)*$ /?system=$1&id=$2 break;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent; 

location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files  $uri =404;

       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;

       fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/usr/share/nginx/html/web/config.php";
    }

}
```

Comment: when you say `allow localhost` - what do you mean in terms of URL host? Is it going to be `http://localhost/something`?

Comment: That means, I deny all queries except those, which done by server itself ( like POST, etc.)

Comment: POST where: to `http://localhost/my.php` or to `http://my.domain.com/my.php`?

Comment: to `http://my.domain.com/my.php`

Comment: So host header is going to be the same for external and local requests in that case. And the only way to distinguish them is by source IP address containing in $remote_addr variable. Honestly, I do not think you want go that far. Maybe rather address your server as localhost for local request, then the problem boils down to defining 2 servers with only difference in `listen` directive.

Comment: As for distinguishing between `index.php` and `anythingelse.php` you may want just add another `location` block with specific definition of `index.php` URI. Then more specific location will trump more generic wildcard one you have there now. Accordingly, you can manage behaviour separately. I would not recommend using `if()` for what you trying to do, although it is possible.

Comment: The point is, usually the webpage is accessed via slash: `myweb.com/`, without any `index.php`. Could you please write yor answer in answer form?

Comment: Well if that's the only point you have by now - life must be good :-) To address that, use try_files at server level. In that case, nginx first forms full URI and then match location. Surely, don't remove try_files with different functionality from location level.

Comment: I added my config. Do you have something to change there? I use try_files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's commonly done is that you add a `RewriteRule` to an `.htaccess` file. This makes it possible to redirect all traffic to the `index.php` as you wish.

This solution even allows you to add the requested URL as an URL-parameter, so it is accessible within index.php as a `$_GET` variable.

Since `.htaccess` is only a solution for an Apache server it cannot be applied one-on-one here. This blog post on NGINX's website explains how it's done on NGINX: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: Added config. I should write something in `location ~ \.php` part to restrict the access to .php files. Used `try_files`...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching all PHP files, match just index.php and reject all others, like this:

```
location = /index.php {
  try_files  $uri =404;

  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;

  fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/usr/share/nginx/html/web/config.php";      
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  return 301 $scheme://$http_host/index.php;
}
```

If you want to allow posts from the server to itself add the following for the URI

```
location = /post.php {
  allow 127.0.0.1/24;
  deny all;

  try_files  $uri =404;

  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;

  fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/usr/share/nginx/html/web/config.php";      
}
```

**Edit: Alternative Configuration**

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location = /index.php {
    try_files  $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/usr/share/nginx/html/web/config.php";      
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host/index.php;
  }
}

server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:81;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files  $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/usr/share/nginx/html/web/config.php";      
  }
}
```

Local requests would then need to be directed to port 81, ie:

```
curl http://localhost:81/myscript.php
```

Comment: What is post.php?

Comment: Just an example, you said the server had to post some data to itself via locahost, adjust this to suit.

Comment: There are a lot of files, I can't write a rout for all of them

Comment: Then write a regexp for them: `location ~^ /(post|example|another/example)\.php$ {`

Comment: What about 100 files? )

Comment: In that instance I would run a server listening on localhost only and omit all the deny/allow clauses and specific location checks. `server { listen 127.0.0.1:80;`. You would also need to use a different server name, and/or port.